# Time manipulation in React using momentjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, datetime-format

I'm working on an attendance managing project right now where an employee should time-in, time-out or break (in a table like structure), and if they time-in in 15 minutes after the actual time-in time, the time-in cell in the table will become red (because they are late).

The condition of making the cell red is easy and other stuffs but the only thing that is wasting my time is how can I manipulate time? How can I know that the time-in exceeds 15 minutes before an actual time (for example greater than 8:15am is late where 8:00am is the actual time-in time) if the value of this data from the database is a string (they already used moment in db so the data that will return to me is time already converted into a string)

I'm using moment in React and es6, but I don't know how can I manipulate time using moment (or any other methods).

Comment: The short answer: pass the date string to moment contructor, then just use normal greater / less than equality. Example: `moment('23 December 2015') > moment('23 December 2016') // false`

Comment: @azium - Please don't put answers in comments.  It makes it impossible for you to earn points - or in this case to downvote.  (You shouldn't pass a format like that one without a format specifier, and it's better to use `isBefore` / `isAfter`)

Comment: @ExzavierZ - Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then search, show what you've tried, etc.  You should also read [the moment.js docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) as there are plenty of examples to learn from.